# How to use function column in select query

Tags: amazon-redshift

```
select now() as t1,t1;
```

> error :- ERROR: 42703: column "t1" does not exist

Result should be :

```
select now() as t1,t1;

7/26/2016   7/26/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not work because the moment you execute the `select`, the column `t1` is not defined yet. Also, as you've tagged your question with Amazon Redshift, let me note that you won't be able to use `now()` but could use `getdate()` instead.

To solve your problem, you can either duplicate the `now()`/`getdate()` logic:

```
select getdate() as t1, getdate() as t1;
```

Or use it once from a subselect:

```
select t1, t1 from (select getdate() as t1);
```

Either one will give you:

```
              t1              |              t1
------------------------------+------------------------------
 2016-07-28 06:43:46.23357+00 | 2016-07-28 06:43:46.23357+00
(1 row)
```

If you need the output to look exactly like you stated in your question:

```
select
    t1
  , t1
from (
    select
        regexp_replace(
            to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') -- gives 07/26/2016
          , '0([0-9]{1}\/)'                     -- stores "7/" in $1
          , '$1'
        ) as t1
);
```

Giving:

```
    t1     |    t1
-----------+-----------
 7/28/2016 | 7/28/2016
(1 row)
```